# C Insert Struct Into LinkedList

Tags: c, list, struct, insert

Hi I am trying to insert a struct that I have created into a list in ascending order by PID number. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h> //for malloc and rand
#include <stdio.h>

struct PCB
{
    struct PCB *Next_PCB ;
    int PID ;
}*head;

struct PCB *ptr, *tmp, *tmp1;
void insert_ordered (struct PCB *, struct PCB *) ;
void print_list(struct PCB *) ;

main()
{
    int num_structs, i;

    ptr = (struct PCB *) malloc (sizeof (struct PCB)) ;
    num_structs = 10 + (rand() % 10) ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < num_structs ; i++)
    {
        tmp = (struct PCB *) malloc (sizeof(struct PCB)) ;
        tmp->PID = rand() % 20 ;
        tmp->Next_PCB = NULL ;
        insert_ordered(ptr, tmp) ;
    }
    print_list(ptr);
}

void insert_ordered (struct PCB *Head, struct PCB *Add)
{
    if (Head->Next_PCB == Head) {
        Head = Add;
    }
}

void print_list(struct PCB *Head)
{
    while (Head != NULL) {
        if (Head->Next_PCB != NULL) {
            printf("PID: %d\n", Head->PID);
            Head = Head->Next_PCB;
        } else {
            printf("PID: %d\n", Head->PID);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Even though the `insert_ordered()` seems like it should print out one time for the time before an element is added it does not an the output is a shown:

> PID: 0

Also, how would I go about properly inserting an element into the LinkedList? I currently have:

```
while (Head != NULL) {
        if (Head->Next_PCB != NULL) {
            if (Add->PID > Head->PID) {
                Head = Head->Next_PCB;
                printf("pid bigger: %d than current pid: %d\n", Add->PID, Head->PID);
            } else if (Add->PID == Head->PID) {
                //Head->Next_PCB = Add;
                printf("adding pid equal: %d to current pid: %d\n", Add->PID, Head->PID);
            } else if (Add->PID < Head->PID) {
                //Head->Next_PCB = Add;
                printf("adding pid smaller: %d than current pid: %d\n", Add->PID, Head->PID);
            }
        } else {
            Head->Next_PCB = Add;
        }
    }
```

which does not work quite properly. It could be a result of my initial if statement not catching correctly, but either way I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance, SOF.

Comment: `Head = Add` in `insert_ordered ` doesn't do what you think it does. It assigns the address held in `Add` to the `Head` pointer. The *caller's* pointer passed in for `Head` (`ptr` in `main()`) is passed by-value and is therefore *unchanged*. Further, the `Next_PCB` member of the allocated node referred to by `ptr` is never initialized, and  invokes *undefined behavior* to evaluate.

Comment: Still can't figure this out :/

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc, rand */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */
#include <assert.h> /* assert */

struct PCB
{
    struct PCB *Next_PCB ;
    int PID ;
};

struct PCB *List, *tmp;
void insert_ordered (struct PCB *) ;
void print_list(struct PCB *) ;

main()
{
    int num_structs, i;

    num_structs = 10 + (rand() % 10) ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < num_structs ; i++)
    {
        tmp = (struct PCB *) malloc (sizeof(struct PCB)) ;
        tmp->PID = rand() % 20 ;
        printf("%d ", tmp->PID);
        tmp->Next_PCB = NULL ;
        insert_ordered(tmp) ;
        printf("\n");
        print_list(List);

        printf("\n");
    }
    print_list(List);
}

void insert_ordered (struct PCB *Add)
{
    struct PCB *Runner = List;
   if (List == NULL || Add->PID < List->PID) {
          Add->Next_PCB = List;
        List = Add;
        return;
    }

    while (Runner->Next_PCB && Add->PID > Runner->Next_PCB->PID){
        Runner = Runner->Next_PCB;
    } 

    if (Runner->Next_PCB && Add->PID <= Runner->PID)
    {
        Add->Next_PCB = Runner->Next_PCB;
        Runner->Next_PCB = Add;
    }
    else
    {
        Add->Next_PCB = Runner->Next_PCB;
        Runner->Next_PCB = Add;
    }
}

void print_list(struct PCB *Head)
{
    while (Head != NULL) {
        if (Head->Next_PCB != NULL) {
            printf("PID: %d\n", Head->PID);
            Head = Head->Next_PCB;
        } else {
            printf("PID: %d\n", Head->PID);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I seem to keep getting a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. I have tried many ways including yours and I have got that error. The code I used is here; http://pastebin.com/vM12B55a